# My UICollectionView does not update if I use async way to get data

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I use the following way to get data, it works fine. The UICollectionView shows the items properly.

```
NSURL *articleUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData *articleHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:articleUrl];
<Process data here>
....
_objects = newArticles;
```

_objects will be feed to UICollectionView.

However, if I use the following async way to get data, the UICollectionView does not show anything.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Perform long running process
    NSURL *articleUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    _articleHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:articleUrl];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        <Process data here>
        ....
        _objects = newArticles;
    });
});
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling this? Are you calling reloadData after getting your data?

Comment: Rinat answered my question. Joel and Sha, I call this in ViewDidLoad. Viruss, thank you for your suggestion. I have moved the un-related code out of the main thread. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually refresh UICollectionView after receiving new data.

```
- (void) reloadData {

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Call this method inside

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        <Process data here>
        _objects = newArticles;
        [self reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where those lines of code are located? Inside `viewDidLoad`?
Any way, after you get your data you'll need to reload your `UICollectionView`
add:

`[_yourCollectionView reloadData];`

Right after:

`_objects = newArticles;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do Process in `myQueue` and only UI update in `dispatch_get_main_queue`

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Perform long running process
    NSURL *articleUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    _articleHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:articleUrl];
   <Process data here>
        ....
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        _objects = newArticles;
    });
});
```

And i think you have to reload your view,

```
    [CollectionView reloadData];
```

If i am wrong correct me .